# Want to go to a particular folder in gmail inbox

Tags: gmail-addons

I am developing a gmail addon. I want after a process is completed on addon I should redirect the user to a particular folder. I am now using setOpenLink but it opens in a new window. I want it to open in same window similar to when we click on any folder.

Can you anyone help?

Comment: Are you referring to labels as 'folder' ? And can you share some of your code ?